# Oracle 10g Float format

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

How can I return from float/decimal value with the following:

```
SELECT 210 
  FROM DUAL
```

...to get:

```
210.00
```

...instead of `210`?

Using pl/sql oracle 10g

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(210, '999.99') FROM dual;
```

More to_char related formats [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT CAST(210 AS NUMBER(3,2))
  FROM DUAL
```

...to get the value as a numeric data type.  `TO_CHAR` with a filter would work, but returns the output as a string.

Reference:

- [CAST](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/cast.php)
- [TO_CHAR](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

Comment: 1. This query raises ORA-01438.  2. `CAST` can not add additional zeros after decimal point. `TO_CHAR` is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the to_char function passing in an optional format string e.g. to_char(210.00,'000.00') would give the desired result. Do a google search for "number formatting in oracle" and you will find some good examples of format strings.

**Edit**
Look for "Number Format Elements" [here](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/sql_elem.htm#34512).